# Raspberry pins go high and low while booting

Tags: pi-2

i have a project in which i use a raspberry pi2 connected to a 4 relay board. The problem i am facing is that while raspberry is booting up or shutting down, its pins connected to the relay board go high and low. Is this normal?

Is it necessary to have a code that initialises the pins in low state?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would take quite a bit of effort to cover all the possibilities raised by your question.  It's much easier to answer if you say specifically which GPIO are causing you a problem.

Comment: Yes it is normal for some pins and no it is not possible to stop it with user code since it is quite a few milliseconds after boot before that gets a chance to run.

Answer (score 1):

The pins might be in a floating state. If you want your pins to stay low unless you tell them not to, the simplest solution would be the use of pull-down resistors: take a 10kOhm resistor for each of your output pins and connect them all to GND in parallel to their original output circuit to draw the pins to low state.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the only way to go especially if the concern is things like relays and motors -- but the OP should also be sure to investigate what the default function of the pins he's using are, because they not all the same and I believe one or two of them can end up driven high because of that, which an external pull-down won't compensate for.

Comment: No user accessible GPIO are in a floating state after power-up.  They are actively driven outputs or (the majority) are inputs with an internal pull-up or pull-down enabled.